# Why is bipartite perfect matching a special case of clique problem?

Tags: graphs, bipartite-matching, clique

In Lovász writes [1] :

> bipartite graph has a perfect matching, which is a special case of the clique problem

Why is bipartite perfect matching a special case of clique problem?

---

1. [The Work of A.A. Razborov](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1990.1/Main/icm1990.1.0037.0042.ocr.pdf) by L. Lovász (1990)

Answer (score 6):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be the bipartite graph.  Construct a new graph $G'=(V',E')$ whose vertices are the edges of $G$, and where we add $(e,e')$ to $E'$ if $e,e'$ are two edges from $G$ that don't touch each other (don't have an endpoint in common).  Now there's a matching of size $s$ in $G$ if and only if there's a clique of size $s$ in $G'$.  In particular, there's a perfect bipartite matching for $G$ if and only if there is a clique of size $|V|/2$ in $G'$.